# How to store Session object in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

How can we store session object(heavy object) across pages in an http session, but not share that session object (new object for each session) across different concurrent sessions?

Comment: You can save/retrieve it to/from session object if you pass `HttpSession` into your controller. Since you have a heavy object, you can store them in a NoSQL like db or use some caching mechanism if your app needs to support many number of concurrent sessions/users.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you pass HttpSession as parameter in a @*Mapping method (in a Controller), you'll automatically get access to the current session.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String someMethod(HttpSession session) {
    // you have access to the session here
}
```

You can store objects in the session by using [HttpSession.setAttribute(String, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

But if you want to have access to **all** sessions, since a thread is automatically created for every session, you'd have to store it in a static variable. In this case, I assume that a map would be what you're looking for so you can identify the session through the session id:

```
static Map<String, HttpSession> connectedUsers;
```

With the session id (`HttpSession.getId()`) as a key and the `HttpSession` as value, you should be able to freely access the different sessions.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference in the approaches give here : http://blog.chesterwood.io/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including-scoped-proxies.html

Comment: I am trying third approach but facing some issue

Comment: Those are all valid approches, but I prefer passing the HttpSession directly because some actions do not need access to the session, and you can decide whether you pass the session or not with that approach. Also, I'm not sure if all those methods in the blog post are still valid. That blog post is from 2011 after all

Comment: The 4th approach in the blog specified above has become the more frequently used way to go about doing it now. Pros mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

Save session object in spring application context